# upload file with ftp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I upload files to server with ftp though code? my web host apperently dont allow ous to use the "regular" fileupload with in MVC or Web forms anymore on IIS7

I rather not use a third part app
I use asp.net mvc 2, c#

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are various methods but the simplist in my opinion is to make use of the [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) class. There is a nice example of a simple file upload, making use of it, here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I use Rebex FTP for .NET - not free but a great little FTP library.  It allows you to upload using a Stream so might meet your requirements.

http://www.rebex.net/ftp.net/

Comment: Thanks for the reply but my client dont want to pay for extra components at this point.

Answer (score 2):

WCF, maybe, is a choise.

This thread may be help you, [Copy Files to FTP Server using WCF](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/a464446d-0146-48a9-8130-e8a8988d2454/).

Some weeks ago, I just develop a project with WCF. I feel it is powerful and productivity.

Comment: your link is broken. it is missing semicolon after http :S

Comment: Sorry for the broken link. It is fixed. Thanks @tugberk